# strace to discover sudo password persistence location

Tags: memory, passwords, sudo, forensics, strace

strace/dtrace/ltrace ... useful for lots of things, from finding hidden access violations to network socket tracing, but maybe it can't see all.

I haven't been able to figure out using strace (it came up again as I was trying to answer another [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/87078/clipboard-possible-way-to-extract-sudo-password-from-running-system) today) where sudo allocates and persists plaintext passwords in system memory. *The linked question is related if this is news to you.*

The closest I've gotten, with traces like this (this might be a bad example, using a stacked sudo; I've tried a few things):

```
$ sudo strace -ff -o mem sudo -s
Enter password...
```

are lines like this:

```
mem.14471:stat("/etc/profile.d/gnome-ssh-askpass.sh", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=70, ...}) = 0
mem.14471:access("/etc/profile.d/gnome-ssh-askpass.sh", R_OK) = 0
mem.14471:open("/etc/profile.d/gnome-ssh-askpass.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
mem.14471:read(3, "SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/libexec/openssh"..., 70) = 70
```

and I believe I tried tracing those individually, even replacing the env variable in /usr/libexec/openssh-askpass with its own strace, to no avail.

I know how to read and decode straces; I can follow the assigned handles, return codes and memory allocations. What I can't find is a fork that allocates and persists the sudo password (up to 7 times) in memory, while sudo is active. Proof the password's resident is via [LiME Forensics](https://github.com/504ensicsLabs/LiME) applied to CentOS.

Alternatively, would there be a better approach, like iterating process memory allocations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

strace isn't going to show anything as specific as this. The closest you can get is the `brk()` or `mmap(MAP_ANONYMOUS)` calls which glibc uses to grab a whole new memory region. The rest *doesn't use* system calls, just direct memory access.

You might try **`ltrace`** for userspace library calls.

Or just find the password prompt in the source code and look what happens with its results. Add a few `printf()`'s to display the memory addresses.

Comment: Thanks. I remembered realizing/reading that strace may not have access to all system calls (perhaps under SEL) and wasn't 100% certain; this looks like it answers what I was missing. I appreciate the target clarification, what's actually happening, and additional direction.

Comment: Right; whether it has access to system calls or not, you're still looking for something that's not a system call in the first place...